# PHP Verifying passwords using password_verify and password_hash

Tags: php, hash, password-encryption

I'm try to use hash from PHP to encrypt my password save to database. This is my login code:

```
$email=$_POST['email'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$sql ="SELECT user_email FROM tbl_user WHERE user_email=:email ";
$query= $dbh -> prepare($sql);
$query-> bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query-> execute();
$results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
if($query->rowCount() > 0)
{
    if(password_verify($password, $results["user_password"]))
    {
        $_SESSION['signin']=$_POST['email'];
        $currentpage=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'> document.location = '$currentpage'; </script>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<script>alert('Invalid Details');</script>";
    }
} else{

    echo "<script>alert('Invalid Details');</script>";

}
```

and this is my signup code :

```
$user_fullname=$_POST['fullname'];
$user_email=$_POST['email'];
$user_phonenumber=$_POST['telephone'];
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$sql="INSERT INTO  tbl_user(user_email,user_fullname,user_phonenumber,user_password) VALUES(:user_email,:user_fullname,:user_phonenumber,:hashToStoreInDb)";
$query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':user_email',$user_email,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':user_phonenumber',$user_phonenumber,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':user_fullname',$user_fullname,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':hashToStoreInDb',$hashToStoreInDb,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$lastInsertId = $dbh->lastInsertId();
if($lastInsertId)
{
    echo "<script>alert('Something went wrong. Please try again');</script>";
}
else
{
    echo "<script>alert('Registration successfully. Now you can Sign In');</script>";
}
```

I can signup and save the data in my database , after sign up i don't to verify password for login and i stuck at login.
Please help me if i have wrong code or any suggestion code to modify my code. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Your login query is not retrieving the password hash that is stored on your DB.  You need to take the password hash that is on your DB and compare it to the password hash that is generated from the user's password submitted on log in.  I think this should do the trick.

Change your login query to:

```
$sql ="SELECT user_email, user_password FROM tbl_user WHERE user_email=:email ";
```

Also, your query is being returned as an object.  So instead of referencing `$results["user_password"]` you need to reference the variable like `$results->user_password`.

Comment: Ok Sir, i try change to `$sql ="SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE user_email=:email ";`

Comment: @MuhammadWazexr - You will run into other problems as soon as you will allow to change the email address. I would think about storing the user id in the session, instead of the email address, as another benefit the id has no case sensitivity problem.

Comment: @martinstoeckli , can user id store in session if login using email? i try do it, but when i call name by user id. name can't preview

Comment: @MuhammadWazexr - You are free to store whatever you need in the session, it is easy to store the id _and_ the username.

Comment: @martinstoeckli Thanks for suggestion, i will try your suggestion.